# Communication between GrovePi vibration sensor and Raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi

[code][1]I have a GrovePi to connect the [vibration sensor](https://wiki.seeedstudio.com/Grove-Piezo_Vibration_Sensor/) to raspberry pi. I have downloaded the Groove software on my raspberry pi by using the following command:

```sh
cd /home/pi/Desktop
sudo git clone https://github.com/DexterInd/GrovePi
cd /home/pi/Desktop/GrovePi/Script
sudo chmod +x install.sh
sudo ./install.sh
sudo pip install grovepi
```

After this I rebooted my raspberry pi and then when I inside the folder:

```sh
cd /home/pi/Desktop/GrovePi/Software/Python
sudo python grove_piezo_vibration_sensor.py
```

I am getting following errors:

```
Trceback (most recent call last):

File "grove_piezo_vibration_sensor.py", line 49, in <module>
    print(grovepi.analogRead(piezo))
File "/home/pi/Desktop/GrovePi/Software/Python/grovepi.py", line 227, in analogRead
    return number[1] * 256 +number[2]
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

The code that I used was:

```py
import time
import grovepi
# Connect the Grove Piezo Vibration Sensor to analog port A0
# OUT,NC,VCC,GND
piezo = 0

grovepi.pinMode(piezo,"INPUT")

while True:
    try:
        # When vibration is detected, the sensor outputs a logic high signal
        print grovepi.analogRead(piezo)
        time.sleep(.5)
    except IOError:
        print "Error"
```

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong. Thank you!

Comment: Can you please include the code referenced in the error?  There are a few articles already on StackOverflow regarding that error, but without seeing the code, we won't know if any of them are applicable to your situation.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your reply. I have added the code in my post please check it.

Comment: That's progress, but it doesn't highlight the problem.  It looks like the error is being generated by grovepi.py, do you have access to that source, specifically the method that contains line 227?

Comment: here is the link of the code:   https://github.com/DexterInd/GrovePi/blob/master/Software/Python/grovepi.py

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the grovepi code, the `analogRead` function look like this:

```
def analogRead(pin):
    write_i2c_block(address, aRead_cmd + [pin, unused, unused])
    read_i2c_byte(address)
    number = read_i2c_block(address)
    return number[1] * 256 + number[2]
```

You're seeing an exception on that last line, where it was expecting some kind of sequence back from `read_i2c_block` but instead got a single integer.  Looking elsewhere in the code, we see that `read_i2c_block` looks like this:

```
def read_i2c_block(address):
    for i in range(retries):
        try:
            return bus.read_i2c_block_data(address, 1)
        except IOError:
            if debug:
                print ("IOError")
    return -1
```

Now, it looks as if `read_i2c_block_data` (from the `smbus` module) will always return a list.  That means the only way you're getting a single integer back from the above function is if it encounters an `IOError` exception.  This will be masked by the `exception IOError` block, and the function will then return `-1`.

There are a number of problems with this code in the `grovepi` module.  First, anything calling `read_i2c_block` (like the `analogRead` function) should be checking for the `-1` return value.  Second, masking the exception like this isn't particularly helpful, because the exception probably contains information that would point to the source of the problem.  Consider replacing the above code with:

```
    for i in range(retries):
        try:
            return bus.read_i2c_block_data(address, 1)
        except IOError:
            if debug:
                raise
```

And then enable debug mode.  That should be something like:

```
import grovepi
grovepi.debug = 1
```

Now, run your code, and you should see the exception. See if it contains any more details about the error.

Comment: Hey, I did what you told me and I am getting "Error" printed infinite times.

Comment: That's because you're catching the IOError in your own code, too. Get rid of the try/except in your while loop for now.

Comment: The only code that prints `Error` is the `print` statement in the `except` clause in your while loop.  I don't see anywhere else in the code you've shown that could be producing that (e.g., there's nothing in `grove.py` that prints that message).  If you want to update your question to include that exact code you're running now (e.g., show your specific modifications) I'm happy to take a closer look.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this error. The problem, as @larsks hints above, is that i2c is not working. You can confirm this with:

```sh
sudo i2cdetect -y 1
```

This will output something like the below image. If you don't see the `04` (in column 4, row 00) then your Raspberry Pi cannot communicate with the Atmega chip on the GrovePi hat.

[image]

You likely need to update the firmware

```sh
# install required packages 
sudo apt-get install python-smbus i2c-tools
```

Then follow the instructions here
https://github.com/DexterInd/GrovePi/tree/master/Firmware

Finally (if you have not already), enable i2C in `raspi-config`